# How to pass the JS console log info to a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables, console.log

How can I pass "result.info.path" from the script below to a global PHP $_POST variable?

```
var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
  cloudName: 'my_folder', 
  uploadPreset: 'preset_unsigned'}, (error, result) => { 
    if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
      console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info.path); 

    }
  }
)
```

Comment: You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or AJAX

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The given code does not contain any reference to PHP. Additionally, why is your question tagged with `global-variables`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass a content to php variable by this way. Because Javascript run after php execute the code and response to browser. Here php is backend/server-side and javascript is front-end/client-side language. So you need to use AJAX to pass a content from client to server.